# Can't make .gitignore file on my server

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, server

I've cloned my github repo to my server, and then ran `git init`, in that order. But .gitignore didn't copy over.  I suppose that's normal? I'm new to this.  I then tried `touch .gitignore` in root directory.  After some googling I tried `touch .gitignore.txt` with plans to edit the file name after I added content. No dice.

Any idea what I'm missing, or how I should add .gitignore to my project's root directory on my server?

Server is running Ubuntu.

Comment: files preceding with dot are hidden files. running `ls` will not show them. Have you tried `ls -a`. If you did could you tell us the error message given when you run `touch .gitignore`. You could also try `stat .gitignore`.

Comment: @Lynch ls -a is exactly what I needed. learned a few new things today, thanks!

Comment: Also, what's the point of running git init after you cloned a repo? git init is used to create a new repo.